# Python3: How to extract last field in a text file

Tags: python-3.x, split

I am using Python3 to search for a string in a text file, but I am unable to retrieve the last field of the match.  Any idea what is wrong?  Here is my code:

```
shakes = open("CFTUTIL_idparm0.log","r")
for line in shakes:
    if re.match("(.*) Local partner identifier (.*)", line):
       myPart = line.split(" ")[-2]
       print (myPart,end="",flush=True)
       print(type(line))
```

This code works with other files except this one [test file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=07975830582141851988).

Comment: Saw a typo, it should be myPart = line.split(" ")[-1]  ----  no matter, this line will not work. if I change the line to myPart = line.split[-2], this will produce the desired result.  Not sure why since the separators are space(s) if I dump the line in hex.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you have changes to make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Not sure why since the separators are space(s) if I dump the line in hex.

`split(' ')` and `split()` produce very different results even if all the separators are spaces.

To illustrate, let's take a line from your file:

```
>>> line = '          Local partner identifier    PART     = W096952B                        \n'
```

Now, let's split it on spaces:

```
>>> line.split(' ')
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Local', 'partner', 'identifier', '', '', '', 'PART', '', '', '', '', '=', 'W096952B', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '\n']
```

Now, let's just split it with no argument to `split`:

```
>>> line.split()
['Local', 'partner', 'identifier', 'PART', '=', 'W096952B']
```

Those two are very different.  Consequently, when you take the last element of the split, you retrieve very different results:

```
>>> line.split()[-1]
'W096952B'

>>> line.split(' ')[-1]
'\n'
```

The solution is to use `split()` not `split(' ')`.

#### Documentation

You can read about the behavior of `split` using python's interactive documentation.  Running `help(line.split)` at the command prompt yields:

Help on built-in function split (emphasis added):

> Help on built-in function split:
>
> **split(...)**
>     S.split([sep[, maxsplit]]) -> list of strings
>
> Return a list of the words in S, using sep as the
>     delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
>     splits are done. **If sep is not specified or is None, any
>     whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are
>     removed from the result.**

Note the last line: empty strings are only removed if `sep` is not specified or None.  Once you specify sep as `' '`, then all the empty strings are included, as shown above.